NeurIPS2024 style file: loading caption/subcaption package destroys the set spacing
I'm working with the NeurIPS 2024 style files. My paper loads the subcaption package for subfigure environment, and I noticed that this (and also the caption package) destroys the default (set by neurips_2024.sty) table environment's spacing, specifically, the title spacing. To demonstrate: this is the original table demo code from neurips_2024.tex:
\begin{table}
  \caption{Sample table title}
  \label{sample-table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Part}                   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}
    Name     & Description     & Size ($\mu$m) \\
    \midrule
    Dendrite & Input terminal  & $\sim$100     \\
    Axon     & Output terminal & $\sim$10      \\
    Soma     & Cell body       & up to $10^6$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Which outputs:

The loaded packages are minimum:
\documentclass{article}


% if you need to pass options to natbib, use, e.g.:
%     \PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}
% before loading neurips_2024


% ready for submission
\usepackage{neurips_2024}


% to compile a preprint version, e.g., for submission to arXiv, add add the
% [preprint] option:
%     \usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2024}


% to compile a camera-ready version, add the [final] option, e.g.:
%     \usepackage[final]{neurips_2024}


% to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
%    \usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2024}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors

Now, if I add either \usepackage{caption} or \usepackage{subcaption}, I'll get:

I.e., the spacing between the title and the actual table vanishes. I don't want to use some ad-hoc fixing like
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

Is there a more principled way to fix this issue?
FYI, in neurips_2024.sty, the caption skipping is defined as
% float placement
\renewcommand{\topfraction      }{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction   }{0.4}
\renewcommand{\textfraction     }{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}

\newlength{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}\setlength{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}{7\p@}
\newlength{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}\setlength{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}{\z@}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}

% swap above/belowcaptionskip lengths for tables
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}%
   \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}%
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}

Any suggestion is welcome.

You notice in the copied code that for tables they swap the above abd below skips. This suggests that they want the table captions below the table. The caption package mentions this kind of behaviour.  I think you should specify \captionsetup[table]{position=below}. Please consult the caption manual to get the details.

@PietervanOostrum Indeed this is the case. Thanks!!

I have looked into it, and it is in fact a bit more involved than in my comment, but the solution is still
\captionsetup[table]{position=below}

Explanation: the neurips_2024.sty wants table captions above the tables. This is contrary to the standard LaTeX article style, which has captions always below and therefore has the spacing (10pt) below the tabular and no spacing above. So therefore the neurips_2024.sty swaps these spacings.
However, the caption package detects that the the caption is placed above the tabular and therefore also swaps these spacings. This cancels the swapping done by neurips_2024.sty. So you have to trick caption.sty into thinking that the table captions will be below the tables, so that it doesn't swap. This is done by \captionsetup[table]{position=below}. This command only affects the spacing, not the actual position of the caption, which is where you actually put the \caption command.

I see. I have tested it and it works with a standard table environment. However, it doesn't work with wraptable (which is provided by package wrapfig). It seems like I'll need to put \captionsetup[table]{position=top} when using wraptable to get the correct caption. I guess it has to do with a similar reason as you mentioned, i.e., some weird conflict.

The caption package documentation mentions that there are several packages that give this kind of problems. It has a special setup possibility for wrapfig, like this: \captionsetup[wraptable]{⟨options⟩}

Ah nice, this solves the problem indeed. Thanks a lot!!!
